# COPY doesn't work on Docker prod

Tags: nginx, docker

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
```

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  portfolio:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "80:80"
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` on my Mac, Im able to verify that the `nginx.conf` gets copied into the container.

However, when I run `docker-compose up -d` on my digital ocean prod machine, the nginx.conf file doesn't get copied over! Instead, I find the default `nginx.conf` file in `/etc/nginx`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following worked:

clearing all images and containers, `docker-compose down`, then `running docker-compose up` worked! Docker now copies over my nginx.conf file just file!

To anyone else who is stuck with the same scenario follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)